# Matrix assignment in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to convert a Matlab code to Python, and I'm facing a problem when I convert a line. Am I right or not? I don't know how to do assignment in Python.

Matlab:

```
 for j=1:a
     diff_a=zeros(1,4);
     diff_b=zeros(1,4);
     for i=1:4
         diff_a(i)=abs(ssa(j)-check(i));
         diff_b(i)=abs(ssb(j)-check(i));
     end
     [Y_a,I_a]=min(diff_a);
 end
```

Python:

```
for j in arange(0,a):
    diff_a=zeros(4)
    diff_b=zeros(4)
    for i in arange(0,4):
        diff_a[i]=abs(ssa[j]-check[i])
        diff_b[i]=abs(ssb[j]-check[i])
    [Y_a,I_a]=min(diff_a)
```

the last line gives this error:

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

The problem is in the last line. `diff_a` is a complex number array. Sorry for not providing the whole code (it's too big).

Comment: The error is because python thinks you're trying to assign into two variables and you only have one value.  Instead, just assign to a single variable or extract each piece using the `real` and `imag` methods.

Comment: Is it not `diff_a.min()` rather?

Comment: this also works fine ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `[C,I] = min(...)` in Matlab, it [means](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/min.html) that the minimum will be stored in `C` and the index of the minimum in `I`. In Python/numpy you need two calls for this. In your example:

```
Y_a, I_a = diff_a.min(), diff_a.argmin()
```

But the following is better code:

```
I_a = diff_a.argmin()
Y_a = diff_a[I_a]
```

Your code can be simplified a little more:

```
import numpy as np

for j in range(a):
    diff_a = np.abs(ssa[j] - check)
    diff_b = np.abs(ssb[j] - check)
    I_a = diff_a.argmin()
    Y_a = diff_a[I_a]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify and increase your code performance doing:

```
diff_a = numpy.absolute( np.subtract.outer(ssa, check) )
diff_b = numpy.absolute( np.subtract.outer(ssb, check) )
I_a = diff_a.argmin( axis=1 )
Y_a = diff_a.min( axis=1 )
```

Here `I_a` and `Y_a` are arrays of shape `(a,4)` according to your code.

The error you are getting is because you are trying to unpack a `numpy.float64` value when doing:

```
[Y_a,I_a]=min(diff_a)
```

since `min()` returns a single value

Comment: Note that the OP is using different indices for `ssa` and `check`. Also, `I_a` is supposed to be the `argmin`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are return a single value `min(diff_a)` to a list `[Y_a, I_a]`.

`min(diff_a)` finds the smallest value in the iterable, in this case `diff_a`.  You can't assign one value to a list.  Try something like

```
result = min(diff_a)
```

or just

```
print min(diff_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
min(diff_a)
```

returns minimum object from iterable which in your case is apparently a float, you can't iterate over a float, yet this is what you are trying to do in you assignement:

```
[Y_a,I_a]=min(diff_a)
```

you're essentialy trying to create a new list of two items Y_a and I_a from just one value - which is the result of applying min function to diff_a list.

If you need to get two smallest values from diff_a try this:

```
[Y_a,I_a]= sorted(diff_a)[:2]
```